# How to reset other stack navigators in tab navigator with react-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Here is my nav structure.

```
--SwitchNav
   --Main Tab Nav
      --Stack Nav A
      --Stack Nav B
      --Stack Nav C
      --Stack Nav D (Current)
   --Onboard Stack Nav
```

Somewhere in stack Nav D, I want to reset the stacks of Stack Nav A,B,& C, but I do not want to navigate the user away from the current screen on Stack Nav D.

I've been looking into StackActions.reset, and understand how I would use it to reset and navigate to a specific stack, but how would I use it (or otherwise accomplish) what I've described in the scenario above?

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific way of doing this. A solution would be, without navigating, to do a `this.props.dangerouslyGetParent()` and from that loop trough the 3 childrens and reset them. For example:

```
resetOtherStacks=()=>{
   let parentNav=this.props.dangerouslyGetParent()
   parentNav.getChildNavigation("Stack Nav A").reset()
}
```

And do a reset for every stack you need to reset.

The function `getChildNavigation(ChildKey)` needs the childKey that you defined when you created the `MainTabNav`.

Hope this helps you!